# What is the correct way upload large koa request body to AWS S3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, koa

I'm building a application backend. The clients post file as request body to server, then server uploads the file to AWS S3. Server is using NodeJS and koa web framework.

If I use the `raw-body` to get the post body to buffer, when the file is large, the buffer is large, and cause a out of memory error.
If I directly pass the ctx.req (a IncomingMessage object) to S3.putObject, AWS SDK throws a error says `Cannot determine length of [object Object]`, looks like AWS SDK try to get the length of stream then start multi part upload.

AWS SDK version 2.383.0 (currently lastest)
NodeJS 10.14.2

At this time, I wrote a function that read from IncomingMessage as a stream, wait for data event to fill up a large buffer (16MB) then do the multi part upload to S3, this solves the problem well, but I'm still looking for better solution.

Comment: pls check this https://medium.com/@stephenjwatkins/from-the-browser-to-s3-1798c13d1ee3

Comment: @user1665355 thanks for comment, and for performance reason I tried this solution but not fit my situation, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months running, I think my final solution is stable and reliable.

The main concept is receive from IncomingMessage stream store to a buffer, after the buffer reach a size, then put current part to S3, then continue to read the stream until end.

```
const uploaderLogger = Log4js.getLogger('customUploader');
function customMultiPartUpload(s3, bucket, key, incomingMessage, partSizeInByte) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        partSizeInByte = partSizeInByte || uploadBufferMB * 1024 * 1024;
        uploaderLogger.debug(`part size is ${partSizeInByte}`);

        let uploadId = null;
        let partNumber = 0;
        let parts = [];
        let fileSize = 0;
        let reserveBuffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
        const sendBuffer = Buffer.alloc(partSizeInByte);
        const md5Hash = Crypto.createHash('md5');

        const doUpload = async (uploadBuffer) => {
            if (!uploadId) {
                uploaderLogger.debug('multipart upload not initialized');
                const createData = await s3.createMultipartUpload({
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: key
                }).promise();
                uploadId = createData.UploadId;
                uploaderLogger.debug(`uploadId ${uploadId}`);

                partNumber = 0;
            }
            fileSize += uploadBuffer.length;
            uploaderLogger.debug(`buffer length ${uploadBuffer.length}, total ${fileSize}`);

            partNumber += 1;
            uploaderLogger.debug(`part number ${partNumber}`);

            md5Hash.update(uploadBuffer);

            const partData = await s3.uploadPart({
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: key,
                PartNumber: partNumber,
                UploadId: uploadId,
                Body: uploadBuffer
            }).promise();
            parts.push({
                PartNumber: partNumber,
                ETag: partData.ETag
            });
            uploaderLogger.debug(`etag ${partData.ETag}`);
        };

        incomingMessage.on('data', async (chunkBuffer) => {
            incomingMessage.pause();

            reserveBuffer = Buffer.concat([ reserveBuffer, chunkBuffer ]);
            if (reserveBuffer.length > partSizeInByte) {
                do {
                    reserveBuffer.copy(sendBuffer, 0, 0, partSizeInByte);
                    reserveBuffer = reserveBuffer.slice(partSizeInByte);
                    await doUpload(sendBuffer);
                } while (reserveBuffer.length > partSizeInByte);
            }

            incomingMessage.resume();
        });

        incomingMessage.on('end', async () => {
            uploaderLogger.debug('stream end');

            if (reserveBuffer.length > 0) {
                await doUpload(reserveBuffer);
            }

            if (uploadId) {
                uploaderLogger.debug('uploadId not null');
                await s3.completeMultipartUpload({
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: key,
                    UploadId: uploadId,
                    MultipartUpload: {
                        Parts: parts
                    }
                }).promise();
                uploaderLogger.debug('multipart upload complete');
            }

            const hash = md5Hash.digest('hex');

            resolve({
                size: fileSize,
                hash: hash
            });
            uploaderLogger.debug(`return file size ${fileSize}, hash ${hash}`);
        });
    });
}
```

adjust `partSizeInByte` to fit your server memory usage, too large part size may cause OOM when server is handling many requests, too small part size may less than S3 part limitation.